# Java in netbeans, read image file from java package

Tags: java, netbeans, relative-path, javax.imageio

I wonder if anyone could help? I have been developing a java app which displays images from disk on a jframe. 
Using netbeans I have created a java package called images within my project and stored the images in that package. First off is that the way I should do it If I want them to ship with the app?

I have the following function to read the image:

```
Image readImg(String file)
    {
        Image image = null;
        try {
            File imgFile = new File(file);
            image = ImageIO.read(imgFile);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // System.out.println("Can not Display Image");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (image != null){       
        return image;
    } else{
        return null;
        }
    }
```

My problem comes that I cannot work out the relative filepath to pass to the function. I have got the image to display calling it like so:

```
Image headerImg = readImg("C:\\Users\\D@nb0y\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\GiftAidApp\\src\\images\\galogo.png");
```

Obviously this will completely fall apart if the app is run on any other device. Can anyone give me a heads up as to making this code portable?

thanks very much

Comment: use getResources method

Comment: I'm sorry Thusitha I dont understand the getResources method of  which class I note that imageIO doesn't seem to have a method by that name?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a `JFrame` you're trying to add an image to, it might be better to use an `ImageIcon` instead of an `Image`.

Try this:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/galogo.png");
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
frame.add(imageLabel);
```

This should make the app portable as well if you include you `images` folder along with your project.